# Unable to decrypt: ENC(2nmnp3B) Caused by: org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException: null

Tags: java, spring-boot

I faced with following excepion while encoding application. properties in spring boot also I added following values :

```
jasypt.encryptor.algorithm=PBEWithMD5AndDES
jasypt.encryptor.iv-generator-classname=org.jasypt.iv.NoIvGenerator
```

but:

```
Caused by: com.ulisesbocchio.jasyptspringboot.exception.DecryptionException: Unable to decrypt: ENC(2nmnp3BaQNeNtqZZprVbCHHSnqH3vOGwXGRr7lJc0KU=1). Decryption of Properties failed,  make sure encryption/decryption passwords match

Caused by: org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException: null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figure out that password is corrupted and I encoded again `ENC(2nmnp3BaQNeNtqZZprVbCHHSnqH3vOGwXGRr7lJc0KU=)` and fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Using the two property entries shown in the original post fixed my problem, where I was getting the "Unable to decrypt property: ENC(...)" error.

This is because, for the jasypt-spring-boot-starter artifact, the default algorithm used changed somewhere between version 2.0 and 3.0.  So if you upgrade versions, you need to either re-encrypt your passwords with the new default (PBEWITHHMACSHA512ANDAES_256 as of 3.0.4), or specify the old default (PBEWithMD5AndDES in 2.0.0) in your properties file. You also need to override the iv-generator-classname name, that changed too.